# Pros and Cons of having PUT on Collections for RESTful APIs

Tags: rest, api

### Background

I am making a RESTful API, and like most APIs I have Elements and Collections. In this specific case, I have the following endpoints:

- `/api/v1/Countries`      `GET`    // retrieves the collection of countries
- `api/v1/Countries`       `POST`   // adds a new country to the collection
- `api/v1/Countries/:id`   `GET`    // gets the info of the country with the given id

### Problem

So, my API allows users to add and check a Country's info. But what if I want to update it?

To do this I know I have to use `PUT` (let's not consider `PATCH` for the time being).

There are two ways I can do this:

- `api/v1/Countries`        `PUT`    //updates a list of countries
- `api/v1/Countries/:id`    `PUT`    //updates the country with the given id

In my readings, this is what I found:

- People that **advocate for** the use of both say that it allows for flexibility, as having a `PUT` in the Collection will allow users to update multiple Country elements at once.
- People that **advocate against** the use of both say that this way you will have an API will multiple endpoints doing the same thing (as you can now update a country either via the collection or the element) and that this is a major mistake in API design.

### Question

1. Are there any other pros/cons that I am missing?
2. Is there a definitive "you should do it this way" answer, or does it depend?
3. If I have to choose one, or the other, in which cases should I use the Collections approach, and in which cases should I use the Elements approach?
4. **(OPT)** How would you do it, and which literature would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you've got everything that matters in mind.
2. Of course not, that is an opinion based question.
3. I would only go for the PUT in the `api/v1/Countries/:id` simply because I find it dangerous to allow users to midify the whole collection at once.

Just go with the way you feel more comfortable, that will work the best.